# Making my Unity Game with Stereoscopic View (VR)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, stereoscopy, virtual-reality, durovis-dive

I have built a Unity3D + Google Tango based game on the NVidia Dev. device. Everything seems to work fine, but now I would like to play this game in stereoscopic view (For Dive Goggles). I looked at the ExperimentalVirtualReality example (https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-unity/tree/master/UnityExamples/Assets/TangoExamples/ExperimentalVirtualReality) and was successfully able to port all the prefabs into my game, but for some reason the experience is not satisfactory.

The stereoscopic view of my game tends to over lap with each other when I look through the Dive goggles. The experience is a quite off.

I noticed that there are some public parameters on the TangoVR Player Object in Unity Project for 'IPD in MM', 'Screen Width in MM', 'Eye Offset in MM', etc. Do I have to play around with any of these. What does these values even represent?

Any help or pointers will be greatly helpful and appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all those who helped answer this. Many of my concepts definitely got cleared but nothing got me close to an actual solution. After researching a lot, I finally found this article (http://www.talkingquickly.co.uk/2014/11/google-cardboard-unity-tutorial/)  super useful. it basically tells me to implement the Durovis SDK (https://www.durovis.com/sdk.html) with its Unity package.

Everything was pretty straightforward and experience I got from it was so far the best.

Answer (score 4):

IPD would be Inter-Pupillary Distance, while offset is the distance from your eye to the 'point  of articulation' when you move your head.

This describes it (with pictures!): http://gamasutra.com/blogs/NickWhiting/20130611/194007/Integrating_the_Oculus_Rift_into_Unreal_Engine_4.php

Comment: Measure your IPD here: https://pd.warbyparker.com/ then adjust it on your Dive headset (and hopefully your IPD won't be out of the range you can adjust it on that headset)

Answer (score 2):

I've found when trying to use cardboard lenses on devices with wider displays than the fov of the lenses you get an unsatisfactory experience.
This has to do with the lenses not being in the center of the frame, when focused at the display.

To circumnavigate this with larger devices you can push in the margins of the stereoscopic views. For the tango, with testing standard cardboard lenses I found that things work nicely if they were pushed in about an inch. The apps on the play store, Tango Mini Town and Tango Mini Village do a nice job of demonstrating this work around.

The ideal way to get this working would be with google cardboard and a proper tango tablet 7 inch view controller, but currently the cardboard app is incompatible with the tango. Fingers crossed for cardboard support.

As far as simply playing around with an optimal view points in unity, one can modify the view port rect on the stereo camera inspector menu in unity to get the ideal experience for a specific device with what ever controller you choose.